# Moving a shapefile point to specific coordinates

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, coordinates

In QGIS is there a simple way to move a shapefile point in a shapefile point file to specific coordinates?

Without exporting the points to WKT changing the x,y values and then importing the WKT via delimited text.

I can move the point easily by hand through the Move Features button on the Digitizing toolbar and my current workaround is to import a simple KML file with the point and then by hand move the point feature of the shapefile on top of the KML point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Numerical Vertex Edit` from the `NumericalDigitize` Plugin should do what you want.

It shows you the current coordinates in the layers CRS, and lets you change them to the values you want.

Comment: Thanks I had installed Numerical Vertex Edit, but was getting Python exceptions, I tried it again and it works, perhaps I had the wrong layer selected.

Comment: It would seem to me the kind of functionality, that should be installed by default and not require a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the `NumericalDigitize` plugin, so I looked for another one. I agree with OP that digitizing points by coordinates should be a standard feature of any GIS ;)

---

**ATTENTION**: Do a backup of your file before you start editing it with Lat Lon Tools. My first try went smoothly and without problems. Next thing I know, I'm digitizing points out in the ocean and the tool is also actively getting rid of previously existing points. In other words: **It's buggy**.

---

**Short version:**

1. Install the Lat Lon Tools plugin
2. Start an edit session
3. Click the Lat Lon toolbar button to add a point by coordinates
4. Done

**In some more detail:**

1. Open your plugins manager and search for `Lat Lon Tools`. Install
   it.
2. In the `Layers Panel`, select the layer you want to add points to (this will only work with point layers).
3. Start an edit session by clicking the pencil icon in the `Digitizing Toolbar`
4. Make sure the `Lat Lon Tools Toolbar` is activated by right-clicking outside the activated toolbars in the toolbar section of the QGIS window (confusing, right?) and select the `Lat Lon Tools Toolbar`.
5. Click the right-most button with X,Y and a point shape in it.
6. A new window will open where you are asked to type in the coordinates. ATTENTION: Make sure to first input Y-coordinates, then x-coordinates. This is unusual to do outside the geodetic world, but it's what the tool expects.
7. Confirm point creation and the usual window will open, where you can populate the AT fields with data.
8. Voilà!